# querying Google.Groups

Tags: curl

I did some googling, and came to the script below,
Can anyone help /me and give a clue why this wont log me in to groups.google.com ?

```
#!/bin/bash

tmp=$$.tmp
EMAIL=<email>
PASSWD=<password>

curl -vv --silent https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth \
    --user-agent "Mozilla 5.0" \
    --data-urlencode Email=$EMAIL --data-urlencode Passwd=$PASSWD \
    -c cookie.tmp \
    -d accountType=GOOGLE \
    -d source=Google-cURL-Example \
    -d service=groups2 > $tmp

auth=`grep Auth $tmp | sed 's/.*=//'`

curl --silent \
      --user-agent "Mozilla 5.0" \
      --header "Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=$auth"  \
      -b cookie.tmp \
  "http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.javascript/topics" > $tmp>

cat $tmp
rm $tmp
```

Comment: Can you [please vote to undelete and reopen this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65371880/548225)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't worked directly with `/ServiceLoginAuth`, but from my work with `/Login` and `/AddSession`, my guess is that you are missing some hidden form values used to secure the login.

In this case, I would look at the hidden `#gaia_universallogin` form and attempt to replicate the login flow:

1. Hit `https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth`.  It returns you a form with id `gaia_universallogin` that contains login tokens.
2. Set the POST data to reflect each header of that form, as well as the `Email` and `Passwd` fields (like you are doing now)
3. Set the `continue` parameter (if you like) and POST the request.  You will either be returned a google settings page or the continue page if you've logged in, or a page with another login form if you aren't.

In this case, I suspect you are missing the `dsh` token.