# Remove file in dir where number of matching pattern below a threshold on linux

Tags: file, awk, grep

How can I remove all `*.txt` files within a directory,  where `grep '>' | wc -l` is less than 2?

Example:

```
file1.txt
>BB
>AA
>HHD
file2.txt
>HS
file3.txt
>HHD
>GGS
>HHD
```

Here file2.txt is removed

Comment: Have you tried something already?

Comment: I tried to find out any similar question on internet but I cannot find any code for that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This `awk + xargs rm` solution may work for you:

```sh
awk 'FNR == 1 {if (fn != "" && n < 2) print fn; fn = FILENAME; n = 0} /^>/ {++n} n==2 {nextfile} END {if (n < 2) print fn}' *.txt | xargs rm
```

To make it more readable:

```sh
awk 'FNR == 1 {
   if (fn != "" && n < 2)
      print fn
   fn = FILENAME
   n = 0
}
/^>/ {
   ++n
}
n == 2 {
   nextfile
}
END {
   if (n < 2)
      print fn
}' *.txt | xargs rm
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose I have two files, `file1` and `file2`, and this is the contents:

```
$ cat file1
Contents of file 'file1'
$ cat file2
Contents of file 'file2'
```

Then i could do:

`find * -maxdepth 1 -name "file*" -exec  grep 2 {} \; -exec ls -l {} \;`

which will result in:

```
Contents of file 'file2'
-rwxrwxrwx 1 luuk luuk 25 Nov 28 16:32 file2
```

The `-maxdepth 1` makes sure i do no look in subdirs

The `-name "file*"` will only find files that start with `file`

The `-exec grep 2 {} \;`  will look if there is a `2` in the filename, and, if true

The `-exec ls -l {} \;`  will do an `ls -l` on that file

This last statement can be changed to `rm -f {} \;`, if you want to delete the file.

And, of course, you need to change the `grep 2 {}` to make sure you only find files containing less than 2 `>`.